# Extracting .json file from scrapy to exact form to work with Tipue search

Tags: python, json, scrapy, format

i'm only a newbie in Python and Scrapy, so bear with me. I'm using Tipuesearch in my site and i need to extract scraped data from Scrapy in certain .json format to get the search working. The json file should look like this:

```
{"pages": [
    {"title": "x", "text": "x", "tags": "x", "url": "x"},
    {"title": "x", "text": "x", "tags": "x", "url": "x"},
    {"title": "x", "text": "x", "tags": "x", "url": "x"}
]}
```

But after hours of testing different things, I only got it to this format:

```
[
{"pages": {"title": "x", "text": "x", "tags": x", "url": "x"}},
{"pages": {"title": "x", "text": "x", "tags": x", "url": "x"}},
{"pages": {"title": "x", "text": "x", "tags": x", "url": "x"}}
]
```

Tipuesearch doesn't recognize this format and that prevents the whole search function from working. How could I get the .json file to the exact format I mentioned first? I run my spider with 
`scrapy runspider techbbs.py -o test.json -t json`
command, and I don't use any pipelines or item exporters.

My spider.py looks like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class TechbbsItem(scrapy.Item):
    pages = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    text= scrapy.Field()
    tags= scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()

class TechbbsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'techbbs'
    allowed_domains = ['bbs.io-tech.fi']
    start_urls = ['https://bbs.io-tech.fi/forums/prosessorit-emolevyt-ja-muistit.73/?prefix_id=1'
             ]

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css('a.PreviewTooltip::attr(href)').extract()
        for l in links:
            url = response.urljoin(l)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        product_title = response.xpath('normalize-space(//h1/span/following-sibling::text())').extract()
        product_text = response.xpath('//b[contains(.,"Hinta:")]/following-sibling::text()[1]').re('([0-9]+)')
        product_tags = response.xpath('//a/span[@itemprop]').extract()
        product_url = response.xpath('//html/head/link[7]/@href').extract()

        items = []
        for title, text, tags, url in zip(product_title, product_text, product_tags, product_url):
            item = TechbbsItem()
            item['pages'] = {}
            item['pages']['title'] = title
            item['pages']['text'] = text
            item['pages']['tags'] = tags
            item['pages']['url'] = url
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by writing a custom item exporter:

1. Inherit from [JsonItemExporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#jsonitemexporter)
2. Overwrite the `start_exporting()` and `finish_exporting()` methods to get the wanted output (if you're having trouble, take a look at [the source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/exporters.py#L97))
3. Activate your exporter by using the [FEED_EXPORTERS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exporters) setting.